# Proving that a subcomplex of a CW Complex is also a CW Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

The following proof is taken from *Introduction to Topological Manifolds by John Lee*

[image]

I believe there is a (slight) error in the proof, where the author says "it is the disjoint union of its cells". Shouldn't it just be the union of its cells and not the disjoint union of its cells?

Furthermore to show that $Y$ satisfies the (W) condition for a CW-Complex, one needs to show that topology of $Y$ is coherent with the family of subspaces $\Gamma =\{ \bar{e} | e \in \xi\}$, which means that $U \subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if the intersection of $U$ with $\bar{e} \in \Gamma$ is open in $\bar{e}$, however only one direction is proved here.

Comment: I think they're disjoint because what Lee calls the cell is the (open) interior $e$, not its closure $\bar e$, which is glued to the lower-dimensional skeleton. Therefore, the cells are all disjoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About your first question: Alex Provost's answer is correct -- the definition of a CW complex guarantees that the cells are disjoint. But maybe you're being misled by the use of the term "disjoint union" -- all I meant here was that $Y$ is equal to a union of cells, and they are disjoint. This is a common informal usage of the term "disjoint union" (described on page 385 of my book), which is different from the ***abstract disjoint union*** defined on page 394.

About your second question: Since $Y$ has the subspace topology, any closed subset $S\subseteq Y$ automatically has the property that $S\cap \overline e$ is closed in $\overline e$ for each cell $e\subseteq Y$. So to prove its topology is coherent with the closures of the cells, only the converse needs to be proved. (I pointed this out on p. 131, just after I defined coherent topologies.)

Answer (score 3):

"Cell" here refers to open cell, so it really is a disjoint union. Look at the author's definition of a cell decomposition:

> A cell decomposition of $X$ is a **partition** $\mathcal{E}$ of $X$ into subspaces that are open cells of various dimensions, such that the following condition is satisfied...

For a simple example, the circle may be regarded as a CW-complex by attaching two ends of a closed interval to a basepoint. Then the circle is the disjoint union of its 0-cell (base point) and the complement of the basepoint, which is homeomorphic to the interior of the interval via the characteristic map.